# Why does my horse keep leaving me?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I got onto a horse in Skyrim (no DLC, Xbox 360). The horse was not stolen but I did not buy it. And whenever I dismount the horse it starts walking away. Why?

This is not a horse I have bought, I just found it in the wild, so this is not a duplicate of [Disloyal Whiterun Horse](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/237084/disloyal-whiterun-horse).

Comment: This is not a duplicate, I didn't buy the horse but I didn't steal it because the text was not in red

Comment: It is answered by the [first of the marked duplicates](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/42974/3610).

Comment: @majortaco42 We know, but the problem is still the same so it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Because you don't own the horse**

The [wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Horses) says following:

> Horses are available as mounts in Skyrim, and improve your movement speed. They are somewhat slower than horses in Cyrodiil but are better at combat and have more endurance. If you fast travel to a city, then an owned horse you are riding will move to the stables outside the city; an unowned horse will return to its starting point. **Only an owned horse will stay where you left it when you dismount. Horses you do not own will begin to travel back to their normal locations if you dismount them.**

Comment: Even if you didn't steal it, and it just said Ride Horse

Comment: Yes, because you do not own the horse.

Comment: And technically the horse *is* stolen, it just doesn't count as a crime.